# How to get access token and social media id from auth0 in nextjs application

Tags: api, authentication, next.js, frontend, auth0

I'm trying to get access token and id token from auth0 login

The **useUser hook only returning the user info**, while I want to get **access token and social media id** of user
which I want to send to my own custom php api
to get user data and validate on my own database,

Kindly help me on this problem and suggest some good approaches according to you

here's my login page code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useUser} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";


const login = () => {
  const { user, isLoading, error } = useUser();
  //all user data here, with tokens

  console.log(user);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="contentContainer">
        <div className="contentRight">
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              flexDirection: "column",
              height: "100vh",
              width: "100vw",
            }}
          >
            {user ? (
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <a href="/api/auth/logout">Sign Out</a>{" "}
                <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
                <h1>{user.name}</h1>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <a href="/api/auth/login">Sign in</a>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default login;
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, You might handle isLoading while API is in progress or error in case of fail, You should use Link component for the Sign In, Inline style could be removed.

Comment: Hey Rahul, did you figure this? I am able to get only id_token for social media based login. Also I am curious do you want access token generated by Auth0 or access_token provided by social media to Auth0 when user authorizes the login

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well.
Please refer to this article:- https://auth0.com/blog/ultimate-guide-nextjs-authentication-auth0/#Next-js-Static-Site-Approach
Check the section of useSWR hook.
Hope that solves the problem.
Other than that - the code you have written in stack overflow - please add  of react-router-dom, instead of  tag, because  tag refreshes the whole page every time.
You can refer:-
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start
Feel free to contact me if you have any doubts regarding this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer doesn't provide a direct solution for OP's question. It would have been better suited as a comment.